# Keep the CloudBlobClient alive during application lifecycle with dependency injection

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection

I want to dependency inject the CloudBlobContainer instance "container" into my custom class.

The question is the lifetime. I could do for Per Web Request or As a singleton because that client will never change when the application runs.

My question is should I expect problems because the blobClient keeps a kind of open connection?

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyDataStorageConnectionString"]
);

CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mydata");
```

Comment: Add a factory around creating a container, stick the container in a Lazy in that factory and inject as singleton? Potentially you will have to create an adapter (wrapper) around the container...

Comment: This is not an answer to my question.

Comment: Are you thinking that the following line of code `CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();` opens a network connection to your Azure Storage account?

Comment: @Elisabeth of course not that is why it resides as a comment!

Comment: @CallumLinington Thanks for the tip. Yes I need to create a wrapper because the container can`t be newed up... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, the Azure SDK gives you an object-oriented API that shields you from the communications details. The way you communicate with the Azure storage services is via HTTP (they're [level 2 REST services](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html)), so keeping `CloudBlobContainer` object around doesn't keep a connection open.

I've never had problems keeping `CloudBlobContainer` objects around for the lifetime of a web application.

Still, according to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.aspx), instance members aren't guaranteed to be thread-safe, so to be on the safe side, you should consider having an instance per web request.

Comment: but keeping the instance longer than a http request doesn`t make the instance more thread safe, right? Thus actually the app lifetime should be safe.

Comment: oh no I fully read the article/docu you posted. Then I could make the container static.

Comment: I see no *reason* that those HTTP requests shouldn't be thread-safe, but I haven't seen the source code, so I can't guarantee anything.